# Como obtener valor mas bajo en la tabla

Tags: tablas, table, lua

tengo una tabla en lua en la cual se estaran agregando numeros
`local numeros = {10, 54,112, 200}`
lo que quiero hacer es como podria obtener el valor mas bajo en la tabla ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua no tiene una función que directamente te dé el mínimo de una tabla, tienes que programar tú una. Hay varios enfoques para esto.

### El más simple

La función `math.min()` te da el menor de los argumentos que le pases. No sirve para tablas, pero puedes *desempaquetar* la tabla para convertirla en una serie de argumentos que sí serían aceptados por `math.min()`:

```lua
minim = math.min(unpack(numeros))
```

El problema de este método es que si la tabla es muy larga puedes obtener un error porque estés pasando entonces demasiados parámetros a `math.min()`.

### Método típico

El método típico sería iterar por los elementos de la tabla y comparar cada uno con una variable que guardaría el menor encontrado hasta ese momento. Si el número que está siendo procesado es menor, se actualiza esa variable. Un problema es cómo inicializar esa variable antes de haber leido ningún dato de la tabla. Una solución sencilla es inicializarlo con el primer valor de la tabla, y luego procesarla a partir del segundo.

Esta idea se simplifica un poco si usas `math.min()` pasándole dos parámetros: el valor del número que está siendo procesado y el mínimo hasta ese momento.

```lua
minim = numeros[1]
for i = 2, #numeros do
  minim = math.min(minim, numeros[i])
end
print(minim)
```

Este mecanismo funciona con tablas de cualquier tamaño (que no estén vacías)

### El código más corto

Finalmente, otro truco puede ser ordenar la lista y después quedarse con el primer elemento. Ya que se ordenan de menor a mayor, el primero una vez ordenada sería el mínimo.

```lua
table.sort(numeros)
minim = numeros[1]
```

Este método es ingenioso, pero tiene un par de inconvenientes. Primero, puede tardar más que el método típico, pues ordenar una lista completa requiere en general más iteraciones que simplemente buscar el mínimo. No obstante esas iteraciones las hace el intérprete Lua (que ejecuta código máquina, mucho más veloz que las iteraciones que puedas hacer tú el Lua), por lo que la diferencia de tiempos posiblemente sólo empiece a notarse en tablas grandes.

El segundo inconveniente, que puede ser importante en tu caso, no lo sé, es que al final la lista `numeros` queda ordenada de menor a mayor, destruyéndose entonces el orden original.